# how to create ImageButtons and link parameters to it depending on a variable?

Tags: android

I need help to build my app. I have an array of Strings `String[] macs=new String [5]`, which will be filled with up to 5 different mac addresses, the number of macs addresses will range from 1 to 5. What I want my activity to do is creating as many ImageButtons as there are macs addresses. Then, I want to populate each ImageButton with a mac address so as to be able to identify each ImageButton by its mac address, so it should be a parameter one can get anytime.

How could I do this?

Comment: At least you should try something and then come back with a more specific question.

Comment: the thing is that I don't where to start... if someone could give me some guidance i would really appreciate it. I've thought that maybe setting the visibility of the imagebuttons depending on how many i want to show could be an option, altough I don't know if the best one... as for populating the imagebuttons no idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a `ListView` and populate it with the addresses, ranging from 1 up to 5 and in the overridden method `onListItemClick`, you can get the position (remembering that address 1 is actually `position = 0`) and perform actions correspondingly, assuming that the first item is always mac id 1, second is mac id 2, maybe with a statement like

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        // Perform action if position = 0 or address = 1
        break;
    case 1:
        // Perform action if position = 1 or address = 2
        break;
    // etc..
    }
}
```

I'm not extremely familiar with it, but I believe `GridView` could also be a lot of help if you have to have it with pictures. Check it out [here at Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html).